# Shopify APIs and Partner program

Tags: shopify

I want to use Shopify APIs and want to develop an node.js application.

To access the Shopify APIs, do I need to become a Shopify Partner?

Also it looks like for creating the partner account a PayPal account is mandatory?

Answer (score 3):

If your app is only intended as a private app for your Shopify store, you don't need to apply as a Shopify Partner. You can create a private Shopify app within your Shopify dashboard. To do so, click on apps, then on the header, click on the right top corner button: Create a Private App:

[image]

Then, choose the name of your Private App and click on Save app.
Shopify will give you the details of your private app (shared, secret...). This data will allow your private App to interact with your Shopify store.

[image]

As per your PayPal question, yes if you want to become a Shopify partner, you need to provide a PayPal email address.

Comment: ill give you an upvote for answering but you should have flagged this to be closed, this is not a programming question as defined in the help center.

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 thanks for upvoting and marking it as a valid answer!